# How to solve the issue of fluctuations in validation accuracy?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I tried using SGD, Adadelta, Adabound, Adam. Everything gives me fluctuations in validation accuracy. I tried all the activation functions in keras, but still, I'm getting fluctuations in val_acc.
Training samples: 1352
Validation Samples: 339
[Validation Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ1Du.png)

```
        # first (and only) CONV => RELU => POOL block
        inpt = Input(shape = input_shape)
        x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same")(inpt)
        x = Activation("swish")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3))(x)
        # x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

        # first CONV => RELU => CONV => RELU => POOL block
        x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same")(x)
        x = Activation("swish")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same")(x)
        x = Activation("swish")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(x)
        # x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

        # second CONV => RELU => CONV => RELU => POOL Block
        x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = "same")(x)
        x = Activation("swish")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = "same")(x)
        x = Activation("swish")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(x)
        # x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

        # first (and only) FC layer
        x = Flatten()(x) # Change to GlobalMaxPooling2D
        x = Dense(256, activation = 'swish')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis = channel_dim)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

        x = Dense(128, activation = 'swish')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

        x = Dense(64, activation = 'swish')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

        x = Dense(32, activation = 'swish')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = Dense(nc, activation = 'softmax')(x)
        model  = Model(inputs=inpt, outputs = x)
```

`model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer  = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])`

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you're solving, what kind of preprocessing you're doing. It is not possible to give reasons/answers looking just at a model.

Comment: Im just normalizing the image by dividing it by 255. No other preprocessing method is used @thushv89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model may be too noise sensitive, see this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255105/why-is-the-validation-accuracy-fluctuating).

Based on the answer in the link and what I see from your model, your network may be too deep for the amount of data you have (large model and not enough datas ==> overfitting ==> noise sensitivity). I suggest to use a simpler model as a sanity check.

The learning rate could also be a possible reason (as stated by Neb). You are using the default learning rate of sgd (which is 0.01, maybe too high). Try with 1.e-3 or below.

Comment: Thanks. Reducing the layers and making it less deep helped me to solve the issue.